# How to load HTML before loading JavaScript/Asking user for input using prompt

Tags: javascript, html, function, callback, prompt

I need the page to run like this: The HTML loads, and the first prompt asks user for input. Prompt is submitted, and the running total is changed and the page displays it. Second prompt is asked, submitted, and then running total is changed and displayed again. Same thing for the final prompt. I believe everything is working completely fine except I can't find a way to make the prompts show up after all of the HTML is loaded, and for the total to update and be displayed after each prompt. I've tried window.onload, setTimeout, DOMContentLoader, etc. but none of them seem to work.

```js
function addPaintAndSupplies(totalCost, callback) {
  let cost = prompt("Enter the cost for the paint and supplies :");
  cost = parseFloat(cost);
  if (cost > 100) {
    cost *= 1.1;
  }
  // Get a handle for the paint paragraph
  let paintArea = document.querySelector(".paint");
  paintArea.innerHTML = `Paint $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  callback(totalCost + cost);
  return (totalCost + cost);
}

const addFloorCoverings = function(totalCost, callback) {
  let cost = prompt("Enter the cost for the floor coverings :");
  cost = parseFloat(cost);
  if (cost < 500) {
    cost *= .85;
  }
  // Get a handle for the floor coverings paragraph
  let floorCoveringsArea = document.querySelector(".floorCoverings");
  floorCoveringsArea.innerHTML = `Floor Coverings $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  callback(totalCost + cost);
  return (totalCost + cost);
}

const addFurniture = (totalCost, callback) => {
  let cost = prompt("Enter the cost for the furniture :");
  cost = parseFloat(cost);
  if (cost < 500) {
    cost *= .90;
  }
  // Get a handle for the furniture paragraph
  let furnitureArea = document.querySelector(".furniture");
  furnitureArea.innerHTML = `Furniture $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  callback(totalCost + cost);
  return (totalCost + cost);
}

const updateTotals = (cost) => {
  // Get a handle for the total cost header
  let totalsArea = document.querySelector(".totalCost");
  totalsArea.innerHTML = `Total $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
}

let totalCost = 0;
totalCost = addPaintAndSupplies(totalCost, updateTotals);
totalCost = addFloorCoverings(totalCost, updateTotals);
totalCost = addFurniture(totalCost, updateTotals);
```

```html
<h1>Reno calculator <img src="2chicks.jpg"></h1>

<p class="paint" style="background-color:grey;"></p>
<p class="furniture" style="background-color:pink;"></p>
<p class="floorCoverings"></p>
<h3 class="totalCost"></h3>
```

In case its needed, here's a video showing how the website should work. https://streamable.com/tss6ar

Comment: In case its needed, heres a video showing how the website should work. 
https://streamable.com/tss6ar

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Window's `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#load_unload_events) to wait for the document to render before prompting the user for input, and you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) with no delay to allow the DOM to update between inputs. Without `setTimeout`, all three inputs are processed in the same event loop, and the DOM is unable to update in between.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  totalCost = addPaintAndSupplies(totalCost, updateTotals);
  setTimeout(() => {
    totalCost = addFloorCoverings(totalCost, updateTotals);
    setTimeout(() => {
      totalCost = addFurniture(totalCost, updateTotals);
    })
  })
})
```

Here's a runnable example implemented this way

```js
function addPaintAndSupplies(totalCost, callback) {
  let cost = prompt("Enter the cost for the paint and supplies :");
  cost = parseFloat(cost);
  if (cost > 100) {
    cost *= 1.1;
  }
  // Get a handle for the paint paragraph
  let paintArea = document.querySelector(".paint");
  paintArea.innerHTML = `Paint $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  callback(totalCost + cost);
  return (totalCost + cost);
}

const addFloorCoverings = function(totalCost, callback) {
  let cost = prompt("Enter the cost for the floor coverings :");
  cost = parseFloat(cost);
  if (cost < 500) {
    cost *= .85;
  }
  // Get a handle for the floor coverings paragraph
  let floorCoveringsArea = document.querySelector(".floorCoverings");
  floorCoveringsArea.innerHTML = `Floor Coverings $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  callback(totalCost + cost);
  return (totalCost + cost);
}

const addFurniture = (totalCost, callback) => {
  let cost = prompt("Enter the cost for the furniture :");
  cost = parseFloat(cost);
  if (cost < 500) {
    cost *= .90;
  }
  // Get a handle for the furniture paragraph
  let furnitureArea = document.querySelector(".furniture");
  furnitureArea.innerHTML = `Furniture $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  callback(totalCost + cost);
  return (totalCost + cost);
}

const updateTotals = (cost) => {
  // Get a handle for the total cost header
  let totalsArea = document.querySelector(".totalCost");
  totalsArea.innerHTML = `Total $ ${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
}

let totalCost = 0;
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  totalCost = addPaintAndSupplies(totalCost, updateTotals);
  setTimeout(() => {
    totalCost = addFloorCoverings(totalCost, updateTotals);
    setTimeout(() => {
      totalCost = addFurniture(totalCost, updateTotals);
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<h1>Reno calculator <img src="2chicks.jpg"></h1>

<p class="paint" style="background-color:grey;"></p>
<p class="furniture" style="background-color:pink;"></p>
<p class="floorCoverings"></p>
<h3 class="totalCost"></h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this

```js
let totalCost = 0;
window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  totalCost = addPaintAndSupplies(totalCost, updateTotals);
  totalCost = addFloorCoverings(totalCost, updateTotals);
  totalCost = addFurniture(totalCost, updateTotals);
});
```

As a good practice you should move the `script` tag to the line before the end of body tag `</body>`

[where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)